# Do rank transformations induce dependence?

Tags: regression, independence, cumulative-distribution-function, ranks

I am interested in an explanation of whether rank-transforming continuous variables induces dependence in model errors that violates the typical i.i.d assumption of generalized linear models.

Suppose I have a sample of $N$ participants, with each participant indexed $i \in [1,...,N]$. Each observation is independently assigned a value of some real-valued variable. Let $x_i$ be the value of $X$ for participant $i$. Now suppose we assign each participant a rank $z_i \in [1,...,N]$ based on the cumulative distribution of $X$.

While each $X$ is assigned independent of other participants, each $z_i$ is dependent on the others since it is based on the CDF. If I understand correctly, this induces local dependence: changing rank 1 to rank 3 does not affect the value for ranks 4 through $N$.

Does this necessarily violate the assumption of independence of the error terms? If so, how is this commonly addressed?

Comment: You appear to be using "independent' in two completely different senses.  At the outset it looks like the definition of probability theory, but by the end it's nothing like that--you're referring to some kind of local operation on data.  What is your meaning of this term??

Comment: What error terms?  You are describing a single variable with no model that would provide error terms that I can see.